# And the little one said "Roll over"

Tags: java, beginner

Below is some code I have written today to test out some bits I have learnt. It isn't much nor is it spectacular. Please critique and let me know what I could/should have done differently or anything I could do to improve it so far.

```
package easy8;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class song99bottles {

public static void main(String[] args) {

// Declare a reference variable of type song99bottles - new object  
song99bottles go = new song99bottles();
// calls the method "queston" for object "go".
go.question();

}

public void question(){

    song99bottles start = new song99bottles();

    String answer;

    System.out.println("Would you like to hear a nursery rhyme?\nPlease enter yes or no:");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    answer = input.next();
    if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
        start.lyrics();
    } else{
        System.out.println("Bye");
    }

}



public void lyrics() {

    int peeps  = 10;
    String intro = "There were ";
    String intro2 = " in the bed and the little one said rollover";
    String fall = "\nSo they all rolled over and 1 fell out.";
    String end = "And the little said 'I'm lonely'.";

    while (peeps > 0){
        System.out.println( intro + peeps + intro2 + fall);
        peeps--;
        if (peeps == 1){
            System.out.println(end);
            return;
                        }
    }


}

}
```

Comment: Missing "one".   "And the little _one_ said 'I'm lonely'."

Comment: According to this video the last line is "There was one in the bed and the little one said 'I'm lonely'"   https://www.youtube.com/v/TdDypyS_5zE%26start=130%26end=138%26version=3

Answer (score 15):

1. Class names should be PascalCase (`song99bottles -> Song99Bottles`)
2. You should indent your code or you will end up with a long code and you don't understand the various `{ }` pairs (and an horrible code!)

   ```
   public class song99bottles {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   // Declare a reference variable of type song99bottles - new object  
   song99bottles go = new song99bottles();
   // calls the method "queston" for object "go".
   go.question();   
   }
   // [...]
   ```

   if you want to follow [Code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html#15395), you code should look like this

   ```
   public class Song99Bottles {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           // Declare a reference variable of type song99bottles - new object
           Song99Bottles go = new Song99Bottles();
           // calls the method "queston" for object "go".
           go.question();
       }

       // [...]
   ```

   Personally i follow the new-line style, but you will see with time you will get "your style".

   i hope you understand the concept. Read [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style).
3. You should give to your variables a more descriptive name, you should understand the scope of the variable by just reading the name. (`song99bottles go = new song99bottles();` `go`? What is? a countdown? I could call it `song` (example))

---

About your code:

1. You create two `song99bottles` objects, why? One inside `main` and one inside `question()`. You should move `question` code inside `main` because `song99bottles` class should just play the song, the main will take care if the user want or not to play the song. Then in your `main`, just call `go.lyrics();`
2. About `lyrics()` code, see Roger answer.

Comment: Java [Code Style Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html#15395) require that the opening brace for a compound statement goes at the *end* of the line, not on a new line. Your `should be` example code is wrong....

Comment: I will edit with that. But i should admit i always follow the "new line" style, i thought the code more clear.

Comment: I understand, and I have worked with both. Two comments though... if you are producing 'example code' it should follow conventions.... and, with the `{` on the next line it looks like C#. Also, by the way, empty-line before method declarations ;-). Your answer is good, it already has my +1.

Comment: About empty-line, yes.. i think i deleted the line by error... Fixed thanks!

Comment: Might as well update my answer too...

Comment: Actually, it appears that this indentation is missing because tabs were used instead of spaces.  I suppose that can still be fixed (I was about to), but I didn't want to invalidate your answer.

Comment: When I writed the answer I had problems to let work code block with numeric list so I think I just do some errors here (spaces problems etc.) Today I will try to fix it by myself..

Comment: `Class names should be camel case` - I think you mean Pascal case. song99bottles *is* camel case

Answer (score 10):

Taking Roger's answer as a starting point, you can also only use one string in the `lyrics()` function, because you always use `intro2` before `fall`. If you use one string, you save an allocation and concatenation.

```
String intro = "There were ";
String fall  = " in the bed and the little one said rollover"
               + System.lineSeparator()
               + "So they all rolled over and 1 fell out.";
String end   = "And the little said 'I'm lonely'.";

for(int peeps = 10; peeps > 0; peeps--){
    System.out.println(intro + peeps + fall);
}
System.out.println(end);
```

Comment: ... I don't even know what to say... Thanks.

Comment: You might want to get the line break sequence from the System object instead of hard coding a newline in the middle of the 'fall' string.

Comment: @atk Like this? It's kinda verbose, but it might save a cross platform headache or two.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of improvements you can make, but removing the declaration for `peeps` in `lyrics()` and changing the `while` loop to a `for` loop would be a good start:

```
for(int peeps=10;peeps>0;peeps--) {
    System.out.println( intro + peeps + intro2 + fall);            
}
System.out.println(end);
```

Answer (score 3):

Suggestion to code

1. Do not create Song99bottles twice, from question() you can call lyrics()
2. Do not + strings, it creates an unbelievable overhead of strings in the stack (memory). Use a string formatter String.format("format %d", integer)
3. Do not use comments unless the really matter. Comments are a sign of bad names and too few funtions, see this http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780132350884/samplepages/0132350882_Sample.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other good advice I see here, I would rename your lyrics method to imply exactly what it does. For example `printLyrics()`.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think to add to others' is that the comments in the `main` method are superfluous.

```
// Declare a reference variable of type song99bottles - new object  
song99bottles go = new song99bottles();
```

It's obvious you're declaring a reference here. You're not adding much by saying it.

```
// calls the method "queston" for object "go".
go.question();
```

This is worse. This is like saying `x = 10; // Sets x to 10`. If you're set on leaving some comments it'd be more beneficial to leave some in the other methods with more logic involved like the `lyrics` method.